# how to remove span tag and class name after scrapping whereas i want to scrape only text using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
for link in soup.findAll('li'):
    if "c-listing__authors-list" in str(link):
    # theAuthor = link.string
        theAuthor = str(link).replace("</p>","")
        theAuthor = theAuthor.split("</span>")[1]
        listAuthor.append(theAuthor)[Output][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `get_text(strip=True)` to get your goal:

```
for e in soup.select('li span.c-listing__authors-list'):
    theAuthor = e.get_text(strip=True)
```

or to get a list in one line:

```
theAuthor = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('li span.c-listing__authors-list')]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=''' 
<ul>
<li><span class="c-listing__authors-list">a</span></li>
<li><span class="c-listing__authors-list">b</span></li>
<li><span>no list</span></li>
</ul>  
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

theAuthor = []
for e in soup.select('li span.c-listing__authors-list'):
    theAuthor.append(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

###### Output

```
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: it worked but i want to get in list

Comment: for link in soup.findAll('li'):
    if "c-listing__authors-list" in str(link):
      theAuthor = str(link).replace("</p>","")
      theAuthor = theAuthor.split("</span>")[1]
      listAuthor.append(theAuthor)

Comment: already provided a solution `theAuthor = [e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('li span.c-listing__authors-list')]` check again please.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is Microsoft (.Net) centric but I'm hoping it may help point you in the right direction.

Its been a while since I've created a scraper.  But I'm thinking this is possible if you also know your XPath as I recall being able to read a webpage into a HTMLDocument, accessing the element you require using XPath then obtaining the text value of it.